# How change the name of property in array of objects good way?

Tags: javascript

Now I have object like this

```
  let arr = [{name:'first'},{name:'first1'}]
```

Exprected

```
  [{value:'first'},{value:'first1'}]
```

My attempt

```
  let result = arr.map(el=>{
  const {name, ...other} = el;

  return {value: el.name, ...other}
})
```

Comment: Your code works. What's the issue?

Answer (score 2):

you can do it that way!

```
let arr = [{name:'first'},{name:'first1'}]  //{value: 'first'}

let result = arr.reduce((acc,el)=>{
  return [...acc, {'value' : el.name}]
},[])
```

Comment: What is wrong with OP's code. Why use `reduce` instead of `map` when the input and the output have the same number of elements?

Comment: It's a matter of preference if the length of output and input array is the same. otherwise reduce is an aggregate function (return a single value in the end), map returns an array of transformed values.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the data using `Array.prototype.map`.

```js
let arr = [{name:'first'},{name:'first1'}]
let result = arr.map(x => {return {value: x.name}});
console.log(result);
```